# Why Java MailSender does not Recognize the destination email?

Tags: java

I have a MailSender class that has 2 methods:

```
private Session createSmtpSession(final String fromEmail, final String fromEmailPassword) {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty ("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "" + 587);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty ("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");


    return Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, fromEmailPassword);
      }
    });
}

public void sendEmail(String subject, String fromEmail, String fromEmailPassword, String content,    String toEmail){
    Session mailSession = createSmtpSession(fromEmail, fromEmailPassword);
    mailSession.setDebug (true);

    try {
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport ();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage (mailSession);

        message.setSubject (subject);
        message.setFrom (new InternetAddress (fromEmail));
        message.setContent (content, "text/html");
        message.addRecipient (Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress (toEmail));

        transport.connect ();
        transport.sendMessage (message, message.getRecipients (Message.RecipientType.TO));  
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot Send email");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ok, The way the above code works is like this:

I have personal gmail  `myEmail@gmail.com` & if I want to send msg to destination email like aa@xyz.com from `myEmail@gmail.com`, then I need to call `sendEmail(subject, "myEmail@gmail.com", fromEmailPassword, content, "aa@xyz.com");`

But recently I bought VPS from Godaddy & I am using Godaddy Email (info@mydomain.com) so I want to send smg to destination email like aa@xyz.com from info@mydomain.com, then I need to call `sendEmail(subject, "info@mydomain.com", fromEmailPassword, content, "aa@xyz.com");`

However I got error cos Godaddy using port 25
So I changed the code  in `createSmtpSession` as following:

```
props.setProperty ("mail.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "" + 25);
```

However, this time I got other problem

```
DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
RSET
250 2.0.0 OK
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <aa@xyz.com> Recipient not found.  <http://x.co/irbounce>
```

Clearly the `aa@xyz.com` is actually existed, but why the error saying `Recipient not found.`

SO How to fix this issue?

Comment: You should open a Support ticket on GoDaddy.

Comment: You need to check this issue with GoDaddy support team .

Comment: what do i need to tell them? many of them don't know Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to look at the outgoing (SMTP) server (like smtpout.secureserver.net) in Godaddy Email  & now it working fine

```
    props.setProperty ("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtps.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.port", "" + 465);
```